# Get value from user and print it using Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, user-input

I want to get value from the user and print it. May be even display it on the UI. I am able to create the UI, just not able to print it.

Done lots of google search.

```
import Tkinter as tkr


t = tkr.Tk()
v = tkr.StringVar()
l1 = tkr.Label(t,text ='Test Name')
l1.grid(row = 0, column=0)
e1 = tkr.Entry(t, bd=5, textvariable = v)
e1.grid(row=0, column =1)
e1.focus_set()
def p():
    v = e1.get()
    print v
b = tkr.Button(t,text = 'Get It', command=p())
b.grid(row =1, column=1)


t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print to the terminal, you just have to remove the () after p in this line:

```
b = tkr.Button(t,text = 'Get It', command=p)
```

The command parameter just takes the name of the function.

Answer (score 0):

and must do print v.get()  instead e1.get()